# Permissions problem with Sonarr move

Tags: permissions, services, log, plex

I am having a problem getting Sonarr to post-process downloaded files, then move them to my Plex media folder. Sonarr runs as myuser and Sabnzbd runs as sabnzbd. Sabnzbd downloads to `/home/sabnzbd/Downloads/incomplete` and my Plex library resides at `/mnt/sdc1/tv` (in this case). I am running Ubuntu 19.10 and the target drive is NTFS.

This is in my Sonarr log:

```
20-3-21 08:45:47.6|Warn|ImportApprovedEpisodes|Couldn't import episode /home/sabnzbd/Downloads/incomplete/<episode name>/8a96bd8519ca4f0db9daf9234a4ae55c.mkv
[v2.0.0.5344] System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
```

I wasn't sure, to what path the error was referring, so I ran this:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /home/sabnzbd/Downloads/
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /mnt/sdc1/
```

To make sure both users can read and write to any sub-directory. That didn't help.

The perms look like this:

```
/home/myuser# ls -l /home/sabnzbd/Downloads/
drwxrwxrwx 30 sabnzbd sabnzbd 4096 Mar 21 08:50 complete
```

and

```
/home/myuser# ls -l /mnt/sdc1/
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Mar 18 15:00  tv
```

I thought that maybe, adding myuser to the groups with permission would help. I ran:

```
sudo usermod -a -G root myuser
sudo usermod -a -G sabnzbd myuser
groups myuser

myuser : myuser root ...truncatedlist... sabnzbd
```

Sonarr is running as a service like this:

```
[Unit] 
Description=Sonarr Daemon After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=myuser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono --debug /opt/NzbDrone/NzbDrone.exe -nobrowser
Type=simple
TimeoutStopSec=20
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Finally, in Sonarr, I updated the path from `/mnt/sdc1`, to `/home/myuser/ShowName` but I'm getting the same error.

During this, I rebooted frequently.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.   (*the file-system types in use may also be useful*)

Comment: Fair point, edited the op to add "Ubuntu 19.10" and "target drive is NTFS".

Answer (score 0):

I removed 'user' and 'group' definitions from the service file (myuser for both). After a service restart, the move started working.